# TCP server creating client socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I am trying to implement a socket programming for server that could also work as a client.

The way that I am trying to do this is while running the server, if I put a command prompt argument "connect IP PORT", it would be connected to the corresponding address as a client.

It does work however, it does not work concurrently.

If I want to connect to a server before this program gets connected by a incoming client, it does not respond until it gets connected with the client.

Here is my code for program.c:

```
#include "clientAPI.h"
#include "serverAPI.h"

int sfd;    //socket file descriptor
int listenv;  //if listen
struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;   //server address
int connectv;


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { //argv[0] == server //argv[1] == port number

        char buffer[256];
        int connection;
        int csfd;
        int n;
        char a1[5], a2[5], a3[5];
        char m1[2], m2[10], m3[50];                 //command arg 1, command arg 2, arg command 3
        int * index;
        char * info;

        struct cEnQuery * ieq;

        ...

        listenv = setServer(argv[1],&serverAddress,&sfd);

        while (listenv == 0) {
            connectv = connector(&sfd);

            //while connected
            bzero(buffer,256);
            fgets(buffer,256,stdin);
            sscanf(buffer,"%s %s %50[0-9a-zA-Z .]",a1,a2,a3);

            if (strcmp(a1,"connect") == 0) {
            //cip = atoi(m2); cport = atoi(m3);
            connection = connectToServer(&csfd,a2,a3);
            if(connection == 1) {
                printf("Please enter the message: "); //command prompt requests [send file/ get file / send struct]
                bzero(buffer,256);
                fgets(buffer,255,stdin);

                //request message to server
                n = write(csfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)); //send prompt request to server to take its actions
                sscanf(buffer,"%s %s %50[0-9a-zA-Z .]",m1,m2,m3);
                if(n < 0) {
                    cerror("ERROR writing to socket");
                }
                else{
                    //connection stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

clientAPI and serverAPI are just header files that include functions.

Would there be any way for me to invoke clientAPI while listening to connections?

setServer() handles binding of server to a host and listens for connections.

connector() accepts the connection and creates a thread and handles the corresponding connection.

connectToServer() creates a socket and connects to the available server.

Comment: How about creating separate threads for each of two functinalities - 1. Listening for client connection requests and 2. Connecting to servers as per user input.

Comment: @cm161 Do you think it could be done by fork() as well?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, if creating child process for each client connection or each server connection meets your requirements, then definitely yes. But before this stage, as per your question, you need to make server connection request processing to be non-blocking by client listening, so definitely multi-thread is one simple solution.

Comment: But I have already done by creating a thread! Thank you @cm161. Post a actual answer and i will give you the tick.